# Disable action bar aniation during a view navigator transition - Flex Mobile?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flex-mobile

does anyone know how to disable that slide animation and just have the action bar instantly change to whatever action bar the next view contains, but still do a slide navigation for the rest of the view. My Action bar doesn't change on every page so seeing the same image reload repetitively in the action bar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem myself too.
This is the solution I used.

I moved all the objects in the navigatorContent, titleContent and actionContent from my views to my ViewNavigatorApplication.

Then I defined a state for each view in that ViewNavigatorApplication.

Next I used the includeIn on the content I moved from my views, and assigned the right state to it.

Now you can use events from the transition from your views to update the state ViewNavigatorApplication.

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication ...>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="customerView"/>
        <s:State name="productView"/>
    </s:states>
    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button id="thisButtonOnlyInCustomerView" includeIn="customerView"/>
    </s:navigationContent>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button id="thisButtonInBothViews" includeIn="customerView, productView"/>
    </s:navigationContent>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

That is a rough example of what the ViewNavigatorApplication will look like.

Since the ViewNavigatorApplication doesnt slide, your actionbar content wont slide along with your view.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had to solve this as the previous answer didn't work and its not really solving the problem.

So here is the fix.

1. Extend whatever effect you wish to use. e.g. SlideViewTransition
2. add the following lines to your extended class **import import mx.core.mx_internal;** and **use namespace mx_internal;**
3. Either inside your constructor set the value (if you don’t wish to change it at runtime) or create a setter to modify the value actionBarTransitionMode to = ACTION_BAR_MODE_NONE
4. When pushing or popping the view, use the created transition.

Without making the answer wordy this is enough info to answer the question but should you wish more information then you can find it here http://kennethsutherland.com/2012/07/11/stop-the-mobile-actionbar-from-transitioning/